# how to check if DOM function exists in typescript before using it

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write

```
if(navigator.share)
{
    navigator.share(...);
}
```

but the typescript compiler is returning the following error : Property share is not found in navigator.

Navigator.share is a function some browsers have while others dont. How do i write my typescript so that the compiler no longer errors while the check is still being made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    if (navigator['share']) {
        const share = navigator['share'];
        share();
        console.log(navigator['share']);    
    }
```

@cyrix continues to insist that this code will throw a compiler error. It will not. Here is a screen capture of the code running

[image]

Comment: With this code, the compiler will complain about `Element implicitly has an 'any' type ...` if the `noImplicitAny` option is set.

Comment: In fact, the compiler does not complain about anything. Maybe your lint file does but the compiler does not.

Comment: In fact, the compiler will complain about it, because `noImplicitAny` is a compiler option, which will [**raise an error**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) if delclarations or expressions implicitly have an `any` type.

Comment: I am looking at the compiler and ran the code and I can tell you for 100% sure that it does not complain about it. In no way does the compiler care. You even use this in your later answer. It's a very valid, simple, and concise way to solve the problem.

Comment: Then you don't have the `noImplicitAny` option set to `true`, look at [**this**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=if%20(navigator%5B'share'%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D)  typescript playground example and activate the `noImplicitAny` option.

Comment: Whatever makes you happy. Just keep piling on conditions and making your answer more and more difficult to parse. If I have to go out of my way to set some compiler option to throw a compiler error to prove someone wrong then I would 1. remove that same bit from my answer and 2. realize that I must not have enough to do. The code above works. End of story.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157175/discussion-between-cyrix-and-chris-sharp).

Comment: I don't need to chat. I write typescript all day every day and this code works for what the OP wanted. It's simple to write and effective. If you don't like it then that's fine with me. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm totally fine with it, then at least consider to add `navigator['share'](...);` to you answer to match OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to check if a property exists on an object:

**1.** If you want to check if an object **owns** a property you use:

```
if(navigator.hasOwnProperty('share')) {
  // ...
}
```

---

**2.** If you want to check if a property is part of the object's `prototype` you use:

```
if(Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator).hasOwnProperty('share')) {
  // ...
}
```

> Note: `navigator.__proto__.hasOwnProperty` whould also be an option, but it's only reliable since the ECMAScript2015 spec.

---

**3.** If you want to check if a property exists on an object  you use:

```
if(navigator['share']) {
  // ...
}
```

**And you might have to check if its type is `typeof Function` before calling it.**

---

So in your case, if `share` is part of the `Navigator.prototype`, you should use the second option. You also have to tell typescript that the navigator has the `share` method, because `navigator['share']()` will fail if `noImplicitAny` option is set.

```
if (Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator).hasOwnProperty('share')) {
  if(typeof (navigator as Navigator & { share: Function }).share === typeof Function) {
    (navigator as Navigator & { share: Function }).share()
  }
}
```

For the TypeScript compiler the `(navigator as Navigator & { share: Function }).share()` part is the important one.

Or you could declare your own global type for the experimental `Navigator.share` method:

```
type ExperimentalNavigatorShare = (data:
        { url: string, text?: string, title?: string }
        | { url?: string, text: string, title?: string }
        | { url?: string, text?: string, title: string }
) => void;

declare type ExperimentalNavigator = Navigator & {
    share: ExperimentalNavigatorShare
}
```

Comment: If you're going to steal the edits then at least add the commas in the last sentence.

Comment: There is another one after the word "prototype"

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, didn't mean to "steal" it. I made an edit myself at the same time.

Comment: I don't get why the 2nd case is what the OP needs to use. He wants the compiler to stop complaining. My answer will absolutely do exactly what he wants. Is there a case where it won't?

Comment: With your code the compiler would still complain about `navigator.share`, use have to use `navigator['share']` or `(navigator as Navigator & { share: Function }).share()`. The extended check is only to make sure you got the right `share` property.

Comment: I did not consider the contents. Thanks for pointing that out. I see your reason now but I still think it's a bit overkill just to get past the compiler on a property that you already know will be there.